# WMIC Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I am trying to use a .bat to get system info with WMIC. I want to create a folder in C:\ with the name of the computer, then have a few .txt files made within the folder with the info on I am seeking. This is what I have so far:

```
start cmd
cd C:\
md C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline
wmic 
/output:C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline\Installed_Software.txt product get name,version
```

This is where my first roadblock is. I get the message that the file name is invalid. The next few are the other .txt files I want to create in that folder as well (Once I can do the first I should be able to apply it to these as well).

```
/output:C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline\Computer_System_Information.txt computersystem get domain,manufacturer,model,name,totalphysicalmemory
/output:C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline\Disk_Drive_Information.txt diskdrive get model,size,manufacturer
/output:C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline\CPU_Information.txt cpu get architecture,currentclockspeed,description,extclock,l2chachesize,manufacturer,name
/output:C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline\BIOS_Information.txt BIOS get serial number,name,smbiosbiosversion,manufacturer
/output:C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline\OS_Information.txt OS get name,cdsversion,manufacturer,freephysicalmemory,buildnumber
```

I also want this to save everything to a folder on my network as well, but that can wait until I get the script going.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand why not to perform the task within current `cmd` instance omitting `start cmd`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions

md "C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline"
wmic /output:"C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline\Installed_Software.txt" product get name,version
```

or using `pushd` - `popd` command pair:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions

md "C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline" 2>NUL

pushd "C:\%computername%_Software_Baseline"
wmic /output:"Installed_Software.txt" product get name,version
     rem further wmic commands here
popd
```

- `PUSHD`: [Change the current directory/folder and store the previous folder/path for use by the `POPD` command.](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)
- `POPD`: [Change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the `PUSHD` command.](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)

> When a UNC path is specified, `PUSHD` will create a temporary drive
>   map and will then use that new drive. The temporary drive letters are
>   allocated in reverse alphabetical order, so if `Z:` is free it will be
>   used first.
>
> `POPD` will also remove any temporary drive maps created by `PUSHD`.